# Channel from. The action you have requested is invalid

Tags: forms, channel-form

I have a main site with mobile template group.

And I have a subdomain for mobile site and it will redirect to the mobile group template in main site.

But currently I am facing "The action you have requested is invalid.
" when form submit to main site url.

anyone know what the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might be running into EE's secure form feature.
Put the following input tag in your form and see if it works out.

```
<input type='hidden' name='XID' value='{XID_HASH}' />
```

Comment: not because of this. I think maybe browser cache problem.